# How to split byte array and send it in small packs in Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c, byte

How to split byteArray in iOS 
Iam getting 160 length of arrayByte data..
I need to split into 4 parts..each part contain 40 arrayByte.that data I need to copy and use for decoding..I tried to converted it but its not working..Can some one help to do this..

Finally i got solution Below is updated working code

```
-(NSMutableData*)decodeOpusData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSMutableData *audioData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    {
        int bufferLength = 40;
        if([data length]>= 40){
        NSData *subData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i*bufferLength, bufferLength)];
        Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(sizeof(Byte)*bufferLength);
        memcpy(byteData, [subData bytes], bufferLength);
        //You can do anything here with data..........
        //Below iam decoding audio data using OPUS library
        short decodedBuffer[WB_FRAME_SIZE];
        int nDecodedByte = sizeof(short) * [self decode:byteData length:bufferLength output:decodedBuffer];
        NSData *PCMData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(Byte *)decodedBuffer length:nDecodedByte ];
        [audioData appendData:PCMData];
        //Decoding audio data using OPUS library
        }
    }
    return audioData;
}
```

Below code is android.i want to do like this..

```
ArrayByte  length = 160
BUFFER_LENGTH = 40

public fun opusDataDecoder(data:ByteArray){
     for (i in 0..3){
        val byteArray = ByteArray(BUFFER_LENGTH)
        System.arraycopy(data,i * BUFFER_LENGTH,byteArray,0, BUFFER_LENGTH)  //BUFFER_LENGTH = 40
        val decodeBufferArray = ShortArray(byteArray.size * 8)  // decodeBufferArray = 320                             
        val size = tntOpusUtils.decode(decoderHandler, byteArray, decodeBufferArray)
           if (size > 0) {
                 val decodeArray = ShortArray(size)
                 System.arraycopy(decodeBufferArray, 0, decodeArray, 0, size)
                 opusDecode(decodeArray)
                 } else {
                   Log.e(TAG, "opusDecode error : $size")
                }
         }
 }
```

Iam getting only first 40 bytes..i want like first 0-40 bytes then 40-80 bytes,then 80-120bytes then 120-160bytes..
But here iam getting always 40 bytes...

Can some one help me how to fix this?

Comment: What about doing `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i ++) { NSData *subData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i*40, 40)]; }` do whatever you need with your subdata (NSData), and convert it to `Byte` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..its working.....

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution for split byte array and send it in small packs

Below is updated working code..

```
-(NSMutableData*)decodeOpusData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSMutableData *audioData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
    {
        int bufferLength = 40;
        if([data length]>= 40){
        NSData *subData = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i*bufferLength, bufferLength)];
        Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(sizeof(Byte)*bufferLength);
        memcpy(byteData, [subData bytes], bufferLength);
        //You can do anything here with data..........
        //Below iam decoding audio data using OPUS library
        short decodedBuffer[WB_FRAME_SIZE];
        int nDecodedByte = sizeof(short) * [self decode:byteData length:bufferLength output:decodedBuffer];
        NSData *PCMData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(Byte *)decodedBuffer length:nDecodedByte ];
        [audioData appendData:PCMData];
        //Decoding audio data using OPUS library
        }
    }
    return audioData;
}
```